# mixing .net techologies

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My company is considering upgrading our old server from Windows 2003 to 2008 and also IIS 6 to IIS 7.

We have multiple websites written in .Net 3.5.  I am not too concerned with the upgrade as I've tested all the sites with an upgraded web.config file and all seems to work.

My question is; is it possible to run MVC 3 together with .Net 4 or 3.5 in the same site (not the same page of course)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC 3.0 is built on top of ASP.NET 4.0, so it's more of a requirement than it is a compatibility thing.

For more information see http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=d2928bc1-f48c-4e95-a064-2a455a22c8f6

Comment: Ah thanks alot, so I can use my existing site and add pages designed in MVC as well.